# How to add an obejct from RecyclerView to database MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I want to add an object from my RecyclerView to database by clicking on its icon. I use MVVM pattern, so I should add a object in Fragment. I have 2 callbacks and second one should add an object to database when by clicking. How can I get object so as to use it in viewModel.saveWord() method in adapter callback. Or I should do it anywhere else?

RecyclerView Adapter:

```
class SearchDefAdapter(
    private var infoListener: OnItemClickListener,
    private var addListener: OnItemClickListener
):
    ListAdapter<Def, SearchDefViewHolder>(differCallback) {
    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SearchDefViewHolder {
        return SearchDefViewHolder(
            SearchWordCardBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            ),
            addListener,
            infoListener
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SearchDefViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
    }
}
```

RecyclerView ViewHolder:

```
class SearchDefViewHolder(
    private val binding: SearchWordCardBinding,
    addListener: SearchDefAdapter.OnItemClickListener,
    infoListener: SearchDefAdapter.OnItemClickListener
): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(data: Def) {
        with (binding) {
            searchCardTv.text = "${data.text} - ${data.tr[0].text}"
        }
    }

    init {
        binding.addSearchCard.setOnClickListener {
            addListener.onItemClick(adapterPosition)

        }

        binding.infoSearchCard.setOnClickListener {
            infoListener.onItemClick(adapterPosition)
        }
    }
}
```

RecyclerView differ callback:

```
val differCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Def>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Def, newItem: Def): Boolean {
        return oldItem.text == newItem.text
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Def, newItem: Def): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

Adapter initialization in fragment:

```
searchDefAdapter = SearchDefAdapter(
            object : SearchDefAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
                override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
                    if (!translationsList.isNullOrEmpty()){
                        val bundle = Bundle()
                        bundle.putStringArray(INFO_BUNDLE_ID, translationsList[position])
                        val wordFragment = WordFragment()
                        wordFragment.arguments = bundle
                        parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
                            replace(R.id.searchFragment, wordFragment)
                            commit()
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            object : SearchDefAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
                override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
                    //viewModel.saveWord()
                }
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your callback parameter from position to your item type.

```
interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(def: Def)
}

//...

class SearchDefViewHolder(
    private val binding: SearchWordCardBinding,
    addListener: SearchDefAdapter.OnItemClickListener,
    infoListener: SearchDefAdapter.OnItemClickListener
): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    private lateinit var def: Def

    fun bind(data: Def) {
        with (binding) {
            searchCardTv.text = "${data.text} - ${data.tr[0].text}"
        }
        def = data
    }

    init {
        binding.addSearchCard.setOnClickListener {
            addListener.onItemClick(def)
        }

        binding.infoSearchCard.setOnClickListener {
            infoListener.onItemClick(def)
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your Fragment, your listeners are easier to define and directly give you the item to write to database.

Comment: It helped! Thank you. Btw is it also to get list size of recyclerview list? Its not obligatory in my project but might be helpful in the future.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the question. For clean design, I would look to the LiveData/Flow in the ViewModel as the single source of truth about data rather than querying a view-related class.